What kind of tool can be used to create a stationary time series from linear combinations of multiple time series?
If I have several time series datasets, what kind of tool could be used to create a stationary time series from a linear combination of these time series?
I suspect that several tools are required to perform such an operation.
Here is my proposal:

There should be a tool which can measure "how close to stationary" a time series is. A measurement of "stationary-ness".
Creating a linear combination of multiple time series is trivial. Each time series is weighted by a parameter, and they are added together in a linear combination.
There should be a tool which can minimize or maximize the above linear combination. There are optimization tools available to perform such an operation.

I do not know what tools might be used in the first of the above cases. This is not a subject area which I have any experience with.
Is there a "tool" or procedure which can be used to measure how stationary a time series is? I think such a tool would need to produce a real number which is sensitive to how close to stationary a time series is.

Have you looked into slow feature analysis (SFA) or forecastable component analysis (ForeCA)?  Fast features and low forecastability features are closest to stationary

@GeorgM.Goerg I have never heard of either, however I greatly appreciate your suggestions and I will look into each in more detail - thanks
